# Seeing duplicate rows in sys.partitions for an index on a non-partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, indexing, azure-sql-database

I'm trying to figure out an odd issue that I'm seeing on an index in Azure SQL Database. I'm not able to repro the issue elsewhere. Checkdb and checktable come back clean.

I have a table with 116 columns and 40 indexes (I know). In looking at the data to grab the Rows data from `sys.partitions`, I found that one of the indexes has two rows. Neither the table or the index are partitioned and if I join it to `sys.dm_db_partition_stats` then I see only one of the rows has data there. There is space used by the second row as it has entries in `sys.allocation_units` (where both rows are in_row_data).

As a curiosity, I did take a look to see if there were any other indexes with the same problem and found another one on a different table.

```
SELECT object_id, index_id, partition_number, count(*) as [# Rows]
FROM sys.partitions
GROUP BY object_id, index_id, partition_number
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

There's nothing odd about either of the indexes - they are basic one or two key columns and a couple of include columns. The indexes themselves appear to be auto-created by Azure as part of the automatic tuning options.

If I create another index on the same columns with the same includes, it does not have multiple `sys.partitions` rows and so this indicates to me that this is not about the index definition.

The extra row does not vanish when performing an index rebuild. I can drop the index and then recreate it, and when recreated, it still have that extra `sys.partitions` row (and also retains the same index_id, which may be relevant).

While I can go ahead and create a new index that matches this one and drop the old one, I'm curious if anyone has seen this before and knows what the cause may be.

Edit: here's an example of the data in `sys.partitions`

| partition_id | object_id | index_id | partition_number | hobt_id | rows | filestream_filegroup_id | data_compression | data_compression_desc | xml_compression | xml_compression_desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 72057594082164736 | 1874105717 | 41 | 1 | 72057594082164736 | 48297 | 0 | 0 | NONE | 0 | OFF |
| 72057594124632064 | 1874105717 | 41 | 1 | 72057594124632064 | 905695 | 0 | 0 | NONE | 0 | OFF |

Comment: can you include the non-grouped output of sys.partitions for those indexes

Comment: Added output for that index as requested @siggemannen

Comment: How many rows are in the table? 905695? Anything in `sys.index_resumable_operations`? (Seems unlikely TBH)

Comment: None there. That was my first though that maybe this was an index operation in progress but that's not the case.

Comment: I presume the number of rows in the table is 905695 and the 48297 is some mysterious extra rows?

Comment: There are 905695 rows in the table. That's the correct number of rows and matches up with the row count for all the other indexes. The 48297 is the mysterious number.

Comment: I don't have an Azure database handy with this option enabled. Is it likely that all indexes created by the auto tuning have this extra entry or do you have counter examples where it hasn't happened?

Comment: Might also be interesting to look at `sys.system_internals_partitions` and see if anything leaps out in the extra info there

Comment: While it's odd that they have different row counts, I do notice that they have different hobt_ids. If you use those to join to `sys.allocation_units` (note - make sure to take a look at the docs on how to do that join, specifically the `container_id` column).

Comment: @MartinSmith I have counter examples where this does not happen for indexes (system_internals_partitions is not available on Azure SQL DB).

Comment: @BenThul both rows show in allocation units (with different sizes of data which makes sense)

Comment: @Nic - that's not surprising. Do you see any other difference in the rows? Like maybe in the type/type_desc columns? Unrelated, when was the last time you checked this database for corruption?

Comment: @BenThul I ran a full checkdb and checktable against this table. I dropped and recreated the index and got the same result (changing the index name does not repro this). There's no difference in the rows other than the partition_id/hobt_id/rows.